# Append text in front of a windows command line output

Tags: windows, command

I have a windows batch file that I need some help modifying. I use it to name our new PC's based on their serial number. I can successfully create a simple batch file that runs the command and copy the output, but I would like to add some text in front of the outputted serial number so I can easily name the PC's with our standard format.

I have tried to find a way to add the text before the command but it either breaks the command or doesn't show up all together.

```
@ECHO OFF
TITLE Serial Number grabber
COLOR 0a
@echo ON
WMIC BIOS GET SERIALNUMBER
@echo off
pause
```

I want the Output to say something like "ABC-Serialnumber" for example, the output in the CMD line windows would output: ABC-1234XYZ

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect the serial number into a text file. Call PowerShell from your batch script to strip away everything except for the number. Then read that into a var to be read with the desired prefix

```
set prefix=ABC
WMIC BIOS GET SERIALNUMBER>Serial.txt
powershell -command "(Get-content Serial.txt) -replace 'VMware-| ','' | select-object -skip 1 | Set-content Serial.txt"
set /p serial=<serial.txt
set Computer_Asset=%prefix%-%serial%
echo %Computer_Asset%
```

The PowerShell line is

- reading the file (get-content)
- replacing *VMWare*- and all *spaces* with null (-replace 'first string to replace|second string, in this case spaces','value to be replaced with'
- Skip first line of file (select-object -skip 1)
- write the new contents to your file (set-content)

Feed the file contents into a serial var.

Now you just set your asset's name with the prefix and the serial (Set asset_tag=%prefix%-%serial%)